# What can I use to store the links of YouTube videos into my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I want to create a video slideshow from scratch for my webpage.

Instead of displaying the videos directly I've managed so far to write a code using JavaScript which takes a YouTube video URL and takes its thumbnail to show it on the slideshow and here goes the problem:

The URL from the video has to be stored somewhere so the script can work properly, I've been hiding the URL inside the HTML code using the "src" attribute but that means I'll have to change it directly in the HTML code every time I want to display a different video on the slideshow.

I was thinking using a database (SQL) to store the URLs, but I read that linking JS/HTML and SQL is a bad practice and brings up unnecessary issues and will bring a headache and not a solution. So where or what can I use to store those URLs and link them properly into my code?

[image: Quick sc of the page]

Comment: Well, you may store links in JSON file and then read it. You have to store them somewhere you know. JSON is better because Javascript can parse it properly and easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database is the right answer, however, for just links, you may not want SQL. I would suggest JSON, but that may not even be necessary here. You can load an array of links from an external JS file. The contents of it would be:

```
var youtubeLinks = [
  'https://youtube.com/link1',
  'https://youtube.com/link2',
  'https://youtube.com/link3'
];
```

If that file was called `script.js` and it was stored in your website root, then you can load it into your HTML as such:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Then in your javascript code that you already wrote, you can pass each link through a loop. Maybe something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < youtubeLinks.length; i++) {
  thisLink = youtubeLinks[i];
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: I decided to use JSON as another JavaScript file didn't convince me. I could get those URLs and even the title of each video with it, thanks!

Comment: @Zlorak, JSON is my personal favorite way to work with data. If you're interested in learning YouTube's API, you can get all kinds of data back about your videos in JSON format and use it to populate templates. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/